# Meteor: how to sort users by most following?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

welcom ...

I have in my Meteor project 2 collections

1 - followers

```
"_id": "_id",
  "follower": "username1",
  "following": "username2"
}
```

2- users

```
"_id": "_id",
  "username": "username",
  [...]
}
```

I would like to sort users by the most following how I can do this

can anyone help me ?....

Comment: Let me know if this helped or worked for you.  If it worked, mark it as the answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest putting the 'followers' collection as an object inside each 'users' document.  There's no point in putting them in separate collections and then having to reference back and forth based on a user's ID.  It's just taking up more space in your DB.  Just make an object inside each user called 'follows' or something similar with the same structure (though make 'follower' and 'following' arrays).  Something like this:

```
"users":{
    "_id":_id,
    "username":"username",
    "follows":{
        "followers":["username 1","username 2"],
        "following":["username 3", "username 4"],
    }
}
```

Once you have it so each user document has it's own 'follows' object, you can sort users by using the 'aggregate' functionality [MongoDB Aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).  This following code sorts based on the length of the followers array.  You'd do a separate one for 'following' swapping out '$followers' with "$following".

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
           "length": { $size: "$followers" }
         },
         { "$sort": { "length": -1 } },
      }
   ]
)
```

This will probably require some tweaking, of course. just helping lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @MohammadKhojaly Of course!  I'm constantly learning new stuff but am amazed at how powerful yet elegant Meteor is.

Here's some articles I found extremely helpful when I was developing in Meteor:  

[Understand Meteor Publish and Subscribe](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Understanding_Meteor_Publish_and_Subscribe) |

[Meteor - Common Mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) |

[Thing I Wish Somone Told Me Before I Started Using Meteor](https://adilapapaya.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/things-i-wish-someone-told-me-when-i-first-started-learning-meteor-js/)